# Replacing symbols with numbers in a system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I'm trying to simulate a physical problem through a system of linear equations in Mathematica.

The system has a complete symbolic answer when the dimensions of the device are not evaluated but when I add them to the solution, the system finds the answers relative to each other and it seems to need three more equations to give independent answers. What could be the cause of the system not having an answer when parameters are replaced with numbers?

Also in a specific case where the initial condition allows the answers to be independent when the dimensions and initial conditions are added before or after the solution of the system, the answer differs. Which answer should i assume to be the correct one?

Here is my system of equations:

```
F1x + F2x == 0
F1y + F2y == 0
-F1y L0 + F2y L0 + T1z + T2z + d F1x Cos[θ1] + 
  d F2x Cos[θ2] + d F1y Sin[θ1] + d F2y Sin[θ2] -
   F1y δ Sin[2 f π t + ϕ] + 
  F2y δ Sin[2 f π t + ϕ] == 0
-F1x + 6 a π µ (Vxc + d Ω Cos[θ1] + 
     d ω1z Cos[θ1] - 
     2 f π δ Cos[2 f π t + ϕ]) == 0
-F1y + 6 a π µ (Vyc - L0 Ω + 
     d Ω Sin[θ1] + 
     d ω1z Sin[θ1] - δ Ω Sin[
       2 f π t + ϕ]) == 0
-F2x + 6 a π µ (Vxc + d Ω Cos[θ2] + 
     d ω2z Cos[θ2] + 
     2 f π δ Cos[2 f π t + ϕ]) == 0
-F2y + 6 a π µ (Vyc + L0 Ω + 
     d Ω Sin[θ2] + 
     d ω2z Sin[θ2] + δ Ω Sin[
       2 f π t + ϕ]) == 0
-T1z + 8 a^3 π (Ω + ω1z) µ == 0
-T2z + 8 a^3 π (Ω + ω2z) µ == 0
```

where the variables I want are:

```
{Vxc, Vyc, Ω, F1x, F1y, T1z, F2x, F2y, T2z}
```

And the initial conditions are:

```
ω1z = ω;
ω2z = ω;
θ1 = θ10 + ω*t;
θ2 = θ20 + ω*t;
```

The specific case that gives independent answers is:

```
ω1z = ω;
ω2z = -ω;
θ1 = -Pi/6 + ω*t;
θ2 = Pi/6 - ω*t;
```

I also found out that, as long as in the initial conditions the absolute value of `θ10` and `θ20` are the same, then the answer is independent; however, as soon as there's a phase difference, the answers become dependent.

The parameters that when I replace with numbers the system seem to not have enough equations are:

```
L0 = 50*^-6;
d = 20*^-6;
a = 5*^-6;
δ = 10*^-6;
µ = 0.89*^-3;
```

Comment: Could you also add the exact expressions you evaluate to solve the equations in each case? Also, have you tried making those replacements in the solutions,  *after* solving the equations?

Comment: I just added the values I want to add instead of parameters if that's what you meant. Also in the one case where the system had answers with these values added, when I checked if I could add these after solving the equations, the answers were not equal, so I don't know which is correct or if I am actually able to do so in all cases.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2004231).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {F1x + F2x == 0,
   F1y + F2y == 0,
   -F1y L0 + F2y L0 + T1z + T2z + d F1x Cos[θ1] + 
     d F2x Cos[θ2] + d F1y Sin[θ1] + d F2y Sin[θ2] - 
     F1y δ Sin[2 f π t + ϕ] + 
     F2y δ Sin[2 f π t + ϕ] == 0,
   -F1x + 6 a π µ (Vxc + d Ω Cos[θ1] + 
        d ω1z Cos[θ1] - 
        2 f π δ Cos[2 f π t + ϕ]) == 0,
   -F1y + 6 a π µ (Vyc - L0 Ω + 
        d Ω Sin[θ1] + 
        d ω1z Sin[θ1] - δ Ω Sin[
          2 f π t + ϕ]) == 0,
   -F2x + 6 a π µ (Vxc + d Ω Cos[θ2] + 
        d ω2z Cos[θ2] + 
        2 f π δ Cos[2 f π t + ϕ]) == 0,
   -F2y + 6 a π µ (Vyc + L0 Ω + 
        d Ω Sin[θ2] + 
        d ω2z Sin[θ2] + δ Ω Sin[
          2 f π t + ϕ]) == 0,
   -T1z + 8 a^3 π (Ω + ω1z) µ == 0,
   -T2z + 8 a^3 π (Ω + ω2z) µ == 0};

var = {Vxc, Vyc, Ω, F1x, F1y, T1z, F2x, F2y, T2z};

val1 = {ω1z -> ω,
   ω2z -> ω,
   θ1 -> θ10 + ω*t,
   θ2 -> θ20 + ω*t};

sol1 = Solve[eqns /. val1, var] // FullSimplify;
```

There is a single solution set

```
Length@sol1

(* 1 *)
```

The expressions are complicated

```
LeafCount@sol1[[1]]

(* 2486 *)
```

**None of the variables are dependent on the others**

```
FreeQ[Last /@ sol1[[1]], #] & /@ var

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

For the second case

```
val2 = {ω1z -> ω,
   ω2z -> -ω,
   θ1 -> -Pi/6 + ω*t,
   θ2 -> Pi/6 - ω*t};

sol2 = Solve[eqns /. val2, var] // Simplify;
```

There is a single solution set

```
Length@sol2

(* 1 *)
```

The expressions are much simplified

```
LeafCount@sol2[[1]]

(* 120 *)
```

**None of the variables are dependent on the others**

```
FreeQ[Last /@ sol2[[1]], #] & /@ var

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)

param = {L0 -> 50*^-6,
   d -> 20*^-6,
   a -> 5*^-6,
   δ -> 10*^-6,
   µ -> 89*^-5};

sol1p = sol1[[1]] /. param // Simplify;

LeafCount@sol1p

(* 2355 *)

sol2p = sol2[[1]] /. param // Simplify;

LeafCount@sol2p

(* 113 *)
```

Comment: So in the first case there is a single answer for each variable, but the answer I get from solve after evaluating the dimensions and the initial condition gives an error: Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. And there is no answer for Omega, T1z and T2z. What is the issue there?

Comment: If you copy and pasted the code that I posted then the difference in results must be due to using different versions of Mathematica. I am using v12.1

Comment: Thank you so much.